# Substitution of rational values of cosine function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry

If $x$ and $y$ are integers $>0$ and
$0 < \theta < \pi/2$ is a real number such that 
$y = x\cos \theta,$
can one conclude that
$$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{2}?$$
Under what conditions $\cos \theta$ is rational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=x \cos \theta$, all we can conclude is that $\frac yx = \cos \theta$. If $\theta = \frac{\pi}4=45^\circ $, then yes we can say $\frac yx = 1$. However, we have $0 < \theta < \frac{\pi}2$, a range of angle values, which means $0 < \cos \theta < 1$.

Comment: Sorry? If $0 < \cos \theta < 1$, isn't the choice $\pi/3$ possible?

Comment: Yes, $\cos \frac{\pi}3 = \frac 12$, which is a rational number.

Comment: For the rational condition, see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442530/are-there-infinitely-many-rational-outputs-for-sinx-and-cosx

Answer (score 1):

By the intermediate value theorem cosine can take any value between 0 and 1 and in particular any rational value. For example there is a $\theta$ whose cosine is 1/3 and then one can choose $x=3$ and $y=1$.